# Store hooks in React Context API as dependency injection. Is it a good pattern?

Tags: reactjs, dependency-injection, react-hooks, react-context

I'm working on shared libraries for multiple projects. And I need to have a flexible way of using hooks not depending on implementation. So I'm using React Context API as a dependency injection pattern.

Simplified example:

```js
const DIContext = React.createContext();

// multiple implementations of common hook useConfig
const useReduxConfig = () => useSelector(getConfig);
const useStaticConfig = () => ({foo: 'bar'})
const useFetchConfig = () => ... //ie fetch config for server

// this will be always static value
const DIValue={
  useConfig: useReduxConfig // ca be any of implementation
}

const App = () => {
return <DiContext.Provider value={DIValue}><SharedComponent /></DiContext.Provider>
}

const SharedComponent = () => {
   // shared component does not care about the implementation of hook
   const {useConfig} = useContext(DiContext)
   const config = useConfig();
   return <div>{JSON.stringify(config)}</div>
}
```

What do you think, is it a good pattern ?

Comment: Well, for one you couldn't use `useFetchConfig` directly within a component, since it'd presumably return a promise for the configuration, and you can't wait for a promise to resolve synchronously within a component body.

Comment: That hook is just an example. You can return an empty object while it's loading external config. I don't see any problem with that.

Comment: How would you signal the component to refresh itself once the configuration is loaded?

Comment: `useFetchConfig` may use `useState` or it can be implemented with some data fetching library. It does not matter. The point of this question is in passing this hook via context api, not the implementation of this particular hook itself.

Comment: My point is this design will not let you easily do all the things you might envision it to. Why put a getter function in the context when you could just put the data there?

Comment: I provided these hooks just for example. It is not real implementation. You don't have to provide only data from hooks. It would be overengineering if I wanted to provide only data. In real life we are using it for compatibility layer between multiple routing libraries or state managements.

Answer (score 0):

This question is opinion-based, here is my view.

I think DI overuses react context, see [use cases for context](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context#use-cases-for-context).

I would not pass down some kind of common react custom hooks to descendants component using react context. Make things complicated.

Illustration from a testing perspective:

Yeah, the DI pattern is good for testing, you can create mock objects with the same interface to replace the real object injected. But this doesn't apply to react custom hooks, we'd better not mock custom hooks, most custom hooks will rely on React built-in hooks, such as `useEffect`, `useState`, and mocking custom hooks that use these built-in hooks will result in the incorrect lifecycle and state update functionality. When testing, you still need to pass the real custom hooks to the context value rather than create mocks for these hooks. **DI doesn't make testing easier as many articles said in this case.**

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export const DIContext = React.createContext<any>({});

const useConfig = () => ({ foo: 'bar' });
// You should NOT mock useLifecycle, we need to use the real useEffect to perform component lifecycle.
const useLifecycle = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useLifecycle mount');
  }, []);
};

export const DIValue = {
  useConfig,
  useLifecycle,
};

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <DIContext.Provider value={DIValue}>
      <SharedComponent />
    </DIContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const SharedComponent = () => {
  const { useLifecycle, useConfig } = useContext(DIContext);
  const config = useConfig();
  console.count('SharedComponent render');
  useLifecycle();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('SharedComponent mount');
  }, []);
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(config)}</div>;
};
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { DIContext, DIValue, SharedComponent } from '.';

describe('DI via react context', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    render(
      <DIContext.Provider value={DIValue}>
        <SharedComponent />
      </DIContext.Provider>,
    );
  });
});
```

For every component that uses context, you need to provide the same context and the real `DIValue`, **NOT** mock `DIValue`. If I use `import` rather than context, I don't need the context provider.

Although DI reduced the code for importing custom hooks in each component, the code for the context provider was added to the test code. Of course, you can create a test util function named `renderWithDIContext` to DRY.

There is another scenario:

If the react custom hook is used by only one component, not a common one, the file location of such a custom hook is usually next to the component file, and the component is imported directly through `import`, it's quick and easy.

E.g.

`SharedComponent.tsx`:

```
import { useA } from './hooks';
import { useContext } from 'react';

const SharedComponent = () => {
  const a = useA();
  const { useConfig } = useContext(DiContext);
  const config = useConfig();

  //...
}
```

The `useA` hook is only used by one component, so there is no need to import the hook into the context provider file and then put it in the context value to pass down. And, other components don't need this hook.

The most you can do are to put some common hooks in the context value.

This scenario mixes the custom hook used by the component itself with the common hook passed down through the context.

**Keep it simple.** Just import and use it.

```
import { useA } from './hooks';
import { useConfig } from '@/common/hooks';

const SharedComponent = () => {
  const a = useA();
  const config = useConfig();
  
  //...
}
```

Besides, putting every common hook in context value and passing them down **violate [interface-segregation principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)**. The context interface is very large, but each component only wants to know about the hooks that are of interest to them, such shrunken interfaces are also called role interfaces. Of course, you can split the large context into smaller contexts. It will increase code and the need to define these role interfaces. We also need to decide how to compose these context providers with our components. Put all context providers in the root `App` component(application level) or page component(page-level) or module level. This adds complexity.

Comment: Thanks. Im trying to solve different problem than testing. We around 30 FE projects and they share some logic. E.g: one project is using redux, another doesn't need redux and last one is using react-query. I'm able to make a hook for each technology to solve this problem in a shared library. So the project can import context for let's say redux and everything from shared libraries will work with redux and they don't have to bother with every component. It is not intended to use for every custom hook, only for technology specific. Yet I'm not completely satisfied with using context in this way.